# Redux form - sync validation example

Tags: redux-form

I am going through the redux form documentation. I have come across this [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/pQj03w7Y6). What I am wondering is where do we get from `handleSubmit`, `pristine`, `reset`, `submitting`, when deconstructing the `props` object in the `SyncValidationForm`:

```
const SyncValidationForm = (props) => {
  const { handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting } = props
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <Field name="username" type="text" component={renderField} label="Username"/>
      <Field name="email" type="email" component={renderField} label="Email"/>
      <Field name="age" type="number" component={renderField} label="Age"/>
      <div>
        <button type="submit" disabled={submitting}>Submit</button>
        <button type="button" disabled={pristine || submitting} onClick={reset}>Clear Values</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  )
}
```

Sinc, from what I could see we only pass the onSubmit property in the index.js:

```
<SyncValidationForm onSubmit={showResults} />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example `SyncValidationForm` is exported as a `reduxForm`:

```
export default reduxForm({
  form: 'syncValidation', // a unique identifier for this form
  validate, // <--- validation function given to redux-form
  warn // <--- warning function given to redux-form
})(SyncValidationForm)
```

This makes it a [Higher Order Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) similar to redux `connect` injecting the extra form props.